# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. C# Interface

Tags: c#, interface

I know this question has been asked quite a few times, and I know the reason I am getting the error is because `LicenseInfoRepository` is null, but I am not sure how to fix it.

```
public abstract class VendorCodeGeneratorBase
{

    protected ILicenseInfoRepository LicenseInfoRepository;
    protected ICountryRegionRepository CountryRegionRepository;
    protected IEnumerable<IBrandModel> BrandModels;

    protected string GenerateVendorCodeUnEncoded(GenerateVendorCodeRequestModel requestModel)
    {
        int formatId = requestModel.VendorCodeFormat;
        var strToConvert = "";
        var brandBytes = new byte[5];
        var brands = LicenseInfoRepository.GetSubscriptionBrandsForVendorCode(requestModel.KeyNumber);
```

The error is happening on the line

```
var brands = LicenseInfoRepository.GetSubscriptionBrandsForVendorCode(requestModel.KeyNumber);
```

I don't know how to instantiate the class that implements the interface.  This is the class

```
public class LicenseInfoRepository : ILicenseInfoRepository
{
    private readonly IEstDbContext _estDbContext;

    public LicenseInfoRepository(IEstDbContext estDbContext)
    {
        _estDbContext = estDbContext;
    }

    public List<VendorCodeSubscriptionBrandModel> 
    GetSubscriptionBrandsForVendorCode(int keyNumber)
    {
        return _estDbContext.SubscriptionBrands
            .Include(sb => sb.Brand)
            .Where(sb => sb.KeyNumber == keyNumber)
            .ProjectTo<VendorCodeSubscriptionBrandModel>()
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

I have a folder named repositories and inside that is the `LicenseInfoRepository.cs` class, and also inside that is a folder named `Interfaces` that has the `ILicenseInfoRepository.cs` interface. That interface looks like this:

```
namespace Data.Repositiories
{
    public interface ILicenseInfoRepository
    {
        List<VendorCodeSubscriptionBrandModel> 
GetSubscriptionBrandsForVendorCode(int keyNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an instance of `IEstDbContext`?

Comment: You haven't initialized LicenseInfoRepository

Comment: @CodeNameJack that's what I thought, but I seem to be doing something wrong

Comment: @JasonStoner note the constructor for LicenseInfoRepository requires an IEstDbContext passed in to instantiate it.

Comment: @ParrishHusband So when I try to pass that in, I get the error "a field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property"

Comment: Please share the constructor for the class that implements VendorCodeGeneratorBase

Answer (score 0):

In the same folder where you have `LicenseInfoRepository.cs`, you need an interface class `ILicenseInfoRepository.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Mvc;
// Add/remove as appropriate

namespace YourProject.DAL // Change to your project / repository folder name
{
    public interface ILicenseInfoRepository : IDisposable
    {
        List<VendorCodeSubscriptionBrandModel> GetSubscriptionBrandsForVendorCode(int keyNumber);
        // Add any other methods that exist in LicenseInfoRepository.cs file
    }
}
```

There may lines missing in you `VendorCodeGeneratorBase` class, especially how you usually instantiate `private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();`. After you add the interface, please share errors / details so we can continue fixing your code.

Comment: I edited the original question with my interface class that I have.